# Is Gen 26:22 (JPS Gen. 26:23) Isaac kvetching?

Tags: hebrew

Some English translations of Gen. 26:22 (JPS Gen. 26:23) could be read as Isaac kvetching that it took a while for the Lord to make room for them in the land, after digging so many wells. But, some translations present Isaac's words as more of a flat statement commenting on the name Rehoboth. I am wondering if instead of this verse being an explanatory comment on the name Rehoboth, it is instead explaining the Lord's comment in v. 24, as His response to Isaac's kvetching. Thoughts?

The JPS for this passage is: He moved from there and dug yet another well, and they did not quarrel over it; so he called it Rehoboth, saying, “Now at last יהוה has granted us ample space to increase in the land.” My question is over the "Now at last" part of the quote attributed to Isaac. Is Isaac kvetching that it took so long for him to have success in digging a well that ended up being uncontested?

The Orthodox Jewish Bible for this passage is:

> And he moved away from there, and dug another well; and for that they strove not: and he called the shem of it Rechovot (Broad Places); and he said, For now Hashem hath made rachav (room) for us, and we shall be fruitful in ha’aretz.

The JPS has "Now at last" where the OJB has "For now". I am wondering if there is latitude in the Hebrew for a reading that has Isaac kvetching at this point where he is saying it took too long for the Lord to provide for an uncontested well, as opposed to the phrase being simply an explanatory statement on where the name "rehoboth" came from.

Answer (score 1):

This question hinges in the translation of the Hebrew phrase כִּֽי־עַתָּ֞ה, which is literally, "for now".  It is thus, that most versions render it.

**Hebrew**

The two words in this phrase are:

- כִּֽי = a conjunction meaning "that, for, when"
- עַתָּה = adverb of time, "now"

Thus, "for now" appears the literal translation as per NIV, LSV, ESV, KJV, NKJV, CSB, OJB, HCSB, ASV, NET, NRSV, NHEB, YLT, WEB, Messianic Bible, etc.  However it is understandable that some may wish to interpretatively translate this phrase as "at last" or similar, as per NLT, BSB, NASB, etc.

**Septuagint**

The Septuagint (completed by Greek Jews in Alexandria about 200 BC) translates this phrase, διότι νῦν = "because now"